# LD_PRELOAD and clone()

Tags: c, linux, ld-preload

I'm using a script to run a program with LD_PRELOAD with a library created by me to intercept some calls, it works well but at some point the process calls clone() and I lose the ability to intercept what's next (the program is run again without my library), is there any way to overcome this?
call is

```
clone(child_stack, 
  CLONE_VM | CLONE_FS | CLONE_FILES | CLONE_SIGHAND | CLONE_THREAD | 
  CLONE_SYSVSEM | CLONE_SETTLS | CLONE_PARENT_SETTID | CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, 
  parent_tidptr, tls, child_tidptr)
```

Looking over the parameters of clone I saw that there is the ability to trace the child process as well, but nothing pertaining to preloading.

I should also mention that I'm trying to intercept all calls on a specific file descriptor and the process clones file descriptors so I'm not even sure if it would be possible to do what I want without some flag to clone (problem is I don't understand all of them).

UPDATE:
I'm using this trying to log all activity done by qemu-dm (which is run by xen)

```
#define _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#define dprintf(...) if(__debug__) { char tmp[256]; int cnt = sprintf(tmp, __VA_ARGS__); _write_f_(2, tmp, cnt); _write_f_(__outfile__, tmp, cnt); }

typedef int (*_open_f_t_)(const char *path, int flags, ...);
typedef int (*_open64_f_t_)(const char *path, int flags, ...);
typedef FILE *(*_fopen_f_t_)(const char *path, const char *mode);
typedef int (*_close_f_t_)(int fd);
typedef ssize_t (*_read_f_t_)(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);
typedef ssize_t (*_write_f_t_)(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);
typedef off_t (*_lseek_f_t_)(int fd, off_t offset, int whence);

static _open_f_t_ _open_f_ = NULL;
static _open64_f_t_ _open64_f_ = NULL;
static _fopen_f_t_ _fopen_f_ = NULL;
static _close_f_t_ _close_f_ = NULL;
static _read_f_t_ _read_f_ = NULL;
static _write_f_t_ _write_f_ = NULL;
static _lseek_f_t_ _lseek_f_ = NULL;
static int __outfile__ = NULL;
static int __debug__ = 0;

void __init__ ()
{
    _open_f_ = (_open_f_t_)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "open");
    _open64_f_ = (_open64_f_t_)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "open64");
    _fopen_f_ = (_fopen_f_t_)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "fopen");
    _close_f_ = (_close_f_t_)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "close");
    _read_f_ = (_read_f_t_)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "read");
    _write_f_ = (_write_f_t_)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "write");
    _lseek_f_ = (_lseek_f_t_)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "lseek");
    unlink("/tmp/qemu-dm-preload.log");
    __outfile__ = _open_f_("/tmp/out-0", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_APPEND);
    __debug__ = 1;
}

void __fini__ ()
{
    __debug__ = 0;
    fsync(__outfile__);
    _close_f_(__outfile__);
}

int open(const char *path, int flags, ...)
{
    //replace this
    int result;
    if (flags & O_CREAT)
    {
        va_list arg;
        int mode = 0;
        va_start (arg, flags);
        mode = va_arg (arg, int);
        va_end (arg);
        result = _open_f_(path, flags, mode);
        dprintf("open(%s, %d, %d) => %d\n", path, flags, mode, result);
    } else {
        result = _open_f_(path, flags);
        dprintf("open(%s, %d) => %d\n", path, flags, result);
    }
    return result;
}

int open64(const char *path, int flags, ...)
{
    //replace this
    int result;
    if (flags & O_CREAT)
    {
        va_list arg;
        int mode = 0;
        va_start (arg, flags);
        mode = va_arg (arg, int);
        va_end (arg);
        result = _open64_f_(path, flags, mode);
        dprintf("open(%s, %d, %d) => %d\n", path, flags, mode, result);
    } else {
        result = _open64_f_(path, flags);
        dprintf("open(%s, %d) => %d\n", path, flags, result);
    }

    return result;
}

FILE * fopen(const char *path, const char *mode)
{
    FILE *result = _fopen_f_(path, mode);
    dprintf("fopen(%s, %s) => %p\n", path, mode, result);
    return result;
}

int close(int fd)
{
    //replace this
    int result = _close_f_(fd);
    dprintf("close(%d) => %d\n", fd, result);
    return result;
}

ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count)
{
    // replace this
    ssize_t result = _read_f_(fd, buf, count);
    dprintf("read(%d, %p, %lu) => %ld\n", fd, buf, count, result);
    return result;
}

ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count)
{
    // replace this
    ssize_t result = _write_f_(fd, buf, count);
    dprintf("write(%d, %p, %lu) => %ld\n", fd, buf, count, result);
    return result;
}

off_t lseek(int fd, off_t offset, int whence)
{
    // replace this
    off_t result = _lseek_f_(fd, offset, whence);
    dprintf("lseek(%d, %ld, %d) => %ld\n", fd, offset, whence, result);
    return result;
}
```

compiled with `gcc -ggdb -shared -fPIC -Wl,-init,__init__ -Wl,-fini,__fini__ -o fileaccesshooks.so -ldl fileaccesshooks.c`

wrapper script contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
export LD_PRELOAD=/home/xception/work/fileaccesshooks.so
exec /usr/lib/xen/bin/qemu-dm-orig "$@"
```

As observed in comments below the environment is actually the same for the task and the process (LD_PRELOAD is the same for both /proc/8408/task/8526/environ and /proc/8408/environ) however after the call to clone no more data is logged
`grep -e "testfile" -e "(11" /tmp/out-0`

```
open(/root/testfile.raw, 2) => 11
read(11, 0x7fffb7259d00, 512) => 512
read(11, 0x7fba6e341200, 512) => 512
read(11, 0x7fba6e341200, 512) => 512
read(11, 0x7fba6e341200, 512) => 512
read(11, 0x7fba6e341200, 512) => 512
read(11, 0x7fba6e341200, 512) => 512
read(11, 0x7fba6e341200, 512) => 512
```

this is what I get, however comparatively the output of `strace -f` run on the same executable contains significantly more reads as well as seeks

Comment: What happens after the call to `clone`? The clone process should have the same `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable set; the environment isn't modified.

Comment: you should be able to look at the environment via /proc/{PID}/environ, does it have LD_PRELOAD?

Comment: there isn't a new process created, just a new task, and it does indeed preserve the environment /proc/8408/task/8526/environ, hmm, guess I have to make some extra checks in the library to get the task id and check if it's the same as the process id

Comment: @Joni I don't think a child process will necessarily have the same `LD_PRELOAD` if it wasn't exported (e.g. `LD_PRELOAD=blah.so ./a.out` vs `LD_PRELOAD=blah.sh; export LD_PRELOAD; ./a.out`).

Comment: @twalberg updated question with wrapper script as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a long investigation here are my findings:

- `#include <unistd.h>` was the **biggest mistake** as it redirects file access calls to their 64-bit equivalents, thus really limiting what I can actually catch (I could only catch the lower reads as the higher ones used read64 or pread64 instead)
- need to implement all functions with both 32-bit and 64-bit versions
- although strace reports a lot of lseek and read calls xen's qemu-dm actually uses pread and pread64 instead (which the same strace reports correctly when using qemu instead for some reason)
- defining _GNU_SOURCE (which is required for RTLD_NEXT) defines off_t to be the same as off64_t so make sure you use the proper types for offsets as the application you are trying to intercept

After removing the `unistd.h` include and implementing open, open64. fopen, fopen64, read, read64, write, write64, pread, pread64, preadv, preadv64, pwrite, pwrite64, pwritev, pwritev64, close I now finally get significantly more output than before and the implementation actually works (there are still some missing file access functions that need to be defined for a complete solution but the reason I opened this question is solved).

Answer (score 5):

From the `clone` parameters of `CLONE_VM` and similar, it looks like this call to `clone` is simply creating a new thread rather than a new process. I wouldn't expect the resulting thread to reload any libraries and therefore I would not expect your preloaded library to need to act again in the new thread - your existing function implementations should 'just work'; all the jump instructions into your library should remain equally valid in the new thread as the old.

I am therefore suspicious that this is not your problem and that the `clone` is a red herring.

My only theories are:

- There's an `exec` somewhere as well
- The `__init__` code in your library is getting called for each new thread, though this seems very unlikely indeed.

One last point regarding qemu specifically - modern `qemu` uses coroutines for lots of IO things. It uses various backends depending on what's available on the host system - if you're unlucky, it creates a thread for each one which can result in very, very large numbers of threads. Read here - http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/qemu-devel/2011-07/msg02894.html - there's some way to get the qemu `configure` stuff to report what coroutine backend it's using. However, I suspect the Xen `qemu-dm` might be too old to have this coroutine stuff? I don't know.

Comment: My initial thoughts were that it should behave like a thread as well, however strace tells me there is much more happening on the file descriptor than what I can intercept... running qemu directly uses pread/preadv/pwrite/pwritev calls instead, also the output of `strace -f -e trace=process,fork,clone ...` only figures the initial `execve` an `arch_prctl`, a few `clone` calls a few `_exit` calls an `exit_group` and some SIGALRM and SIGUSR2. I'm afraid it might be using the syscalls directly and that's why I can't intercept it?!?

Comment: Also a very weird thing and the one that made me suspicious about clone acting as another process is that in order for `strace` to intercept more reads and the seek calls that I don't I had to run it with the `-f` parameter